# c3js Hide data after legend click and data update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

To explain my problem, I use the following code on the c3js website (http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar.html) :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
        // or
        //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        unload : true,
        columns: [
            ['data3', 130, -150, 200, 300, -200, 100]
        ]
    });
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
       unload : true,
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],

    });
}, 4000);
```

- I click on data1 to hide one of the data before it is updated, I have the following, which is normal:

[image]

- But after the final update, I got a weird behavior where data1 is "half displayed":

[image]

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: share your code here, paste it

Comment: To reproduce the issue, please go on the website with the code I provided and click on the legend before the data are updating.

Comment: I can't reproduce issue you sent, it behave ok on my end when I click on legend

Comment: It may be similar to https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2230, what version of c3 did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the drawing logic of c3. But there is a workaround for this issue. Check the following code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        unload : true,
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        done : function() {
            // After chart is drawn, shown all the hidden legend.
            chart.show();
        }
    });
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. By the way, it seems to be a bug only in 0.4.15 and ulterior versions.

Comment: I guess it is the same issue you have mentioned https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2230